# In PostgreSQL, how to deal with error messages that show almost no context?

Tags: postgresql, constraint, exception, domain

Today I realized a number of points where PostgreSQL (v10.3) is rather lackluster and sparse in its error messages.

The first point is illustrated by this code:

```
drop schema if exists X cascade;
create schema X;

create domain X.an_illegal_regex as text check ( value ~ '(' );

create table X.table_with_illegal_constraint (
  a text,
  constraint "column a must have a bogus value" check ( a::X.an_illegal_regex = a ) );

select * from X.table_with_illegal_constraint;

insert into X.table_with_illegal_constraint values
  ( 'xxx' ),
  -- ( 'xxx' ),
  ( 'foo' ),
  ( 'xyx' );
```

This code will throw with

```
psql:db/experiments/pg-error-fail-illegal-regex.sql:17: ERROR:
invalid regular expression: parentheses () not balanced
```

There are several problems with this error message:

FAILURE: the error is really in line 5 where a syntactically invalid
RegEx is created; the fact that it is a RegEx and not a general
string is obvious from the semantics of the `~` (tilde) operator at
that point in time.

FAILURE: the offending RegEx is not referred to and not quoted in the error
message. As such, it could be anywhere in my many, many kLOCs big
DB definition. I cannot even search the RegEx with a RegEx because all
I know is some parenthesis is missing, somewhere: RegExes cannot match
parentheses, and PG RegExes do not have a unique syntactic marker to them.

FAILURE: before the `insert` statement, everything runs dandy. We could have
built an entire data warehouse application on top of a table definition
that can never be syntactically processed but which will only fail when
someone accidentally tries to insert a line.

FAILURE: I can select from a table with a syntactically invalid definition.

The second point is related:

```
drop schema if exists X cascade;
create schema X;

create domain X.a_legal_regex as text check ( value ~ '^x' );

create table X.table_with_constraints (
  a text,
  constraint "column a must start with x" check ( a::X.a_legal_regex = a ),
  constraint "field b must have 3 characters" check ( character_length( a ) = 3 ) );

insert into X.table_with_constraints values
  ( 'xxx' ),
  ( 'foo' ),        /* A: violates first constraint */
  -- ( 'xxxx' ),       /* B: violates second constraint */
  ( 'xyx' );
```

With only line B active, this gives:

```
psql:db/experiments/pg-error-fail-no-constraint-name.sql:16:
ERROR:  new row for relation "table_with_constraints" violates
check constraint "field b must have 3 characters"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (xxxx).
```

SUCCESS: we get the name of the relation *and* the name of the violated
rule.

SUCCESS: the offending piece of data is quoted.

FAILURE: we don't get the full name of the relation, which is
"X"."table_with_constraints". Neither do we get the name of the 
column that received the offending value.

Lastly, with only line A (not line B) active:

```
psql:db/experiments/pg-error-fail-no-constraint-name.sql:16:
ERROR:  value for domain x.a_legal_regex violates check constraint "a_legal_regex_check"
```

FAILURE: no reference to the affected table, column is made.

FAILURE: no reference to the offending piece of data is made.

FAILURE: no reference to the offended constraint is made ("column a must start with x").

What are the best practices or workarounds for the above shortcomings? I've been trying for several hours to figure out what causes an error message a la `value for domain xxx violates check constraint "xxx_check"` by rewriting table definitions,
inserting data row by row and so on, to no avail. What I need is a full chain of the objects (column -> table -> constraint -> domain -> check) that are involved in the error.

Comment: For: *we don't get the full name of the relation, which is "X"."table_with_constraints". Neither do we get the name of the column that received the offending value* . You should name your column constraint in such a way that names are unique so that when PostgreSQL creates an error message with this constraint name you can immediately relate to the table and column having a problem.

Comment: While this is certainly true and I'm all for well-chosen naming, I still think it's the duty of the VM, the language, the interpreter & so on to lay open all pertinent details of the parts & the circumstances that led to an exception. This includes the names of tables, columns were applicable, constraints, the particular instances of data that were involved, and, as far as possible, file names and line numbers. It's clearly an oversight that the table, but not the schema is named in this case. Also observe that I tried to give meaningful names to my constraints but messed up.